# Enable BITS Uploads for virtual directory programmatically in IIS7

Tags: c#, iis-7, cmd, virtual-directory, microsoft-bits

In IIS7 under the feature called "BITS Uploads" for virtual directories, there is a checkbox for "Allow clients to upload files"
I need to enable this checkbox for specific virtual directory and also for "Default Web Site"

Can this be done in C# or even in a command line so I can run it throught script\C#?

Thanks!

**Edit:**
After investigating the changes of applicationHost.config it is possible to modify this Xml file however with a lot of changes (including GUID changes)
But it does not feel right...i hoped that appcmd.exe\c# could supply me a solution for this small but important requirment.
I will be really greatfull if someone can post a better solution for this problem
Thanks,
Lior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured a better way to configure IIS automatically.
For IIS7 you can download an administration pack that lets you generate scripts(C#\javascript\appcmd) for IIS configuration.
In IIS7.5 the administration pack is already integrated as a part of the IIS and it is called "Configuration Editor"
You can find this on the following [tutorial](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/video/iis-75-configuration-editor-windows-server-2008-r2-demo-screencast-2-of-5.aspx)

Thanks for the help you've given me before !

Comment: I am looking for a way to do this myself, and stumbled upon this thread. The use of the Configuration Editor is simple enough, but did you figure out which attributes and values that was required to enable BITS upload? The only differences I can find on an enabled site is under "system.applicationHost/customMetadata", but those dont seem to be enough to enable BITS on another site.

Answer (score 1):

You could modify the ApplicationHosts.config file using c# or any language of your choice as needed: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/373/editing-configuration-files/ (note that you will most likely need an admin account if UAC is enabled)

Comment: Ok I've checked the file and I saw that it is an xml file that hold the configuration for the IIS...However, I don't know which attribute and values I should put in order to "Allow clients to upload files" for "Default Web Site" and virtual directories. Can you please help me with that? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration(VS.90).aspx - it's very handy when you're about to edit configs for IIS 7 and up. Managed .NET library for changing IIS configuration

Comment: The C# generated script in IIS7.5 Configuration Editor uses this dll ;)